# Java REST service generates 405 on POST

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I am developing a JAX-RS REST service. I'm using Java 1.8, Tomcat 7, and invoking my POST through JQuery/AJAX.

My JQuery code is very simple:

```
$.post(ctx + "/addressinfo/", data, null, "json")
```

where data is a simple JSON object containing basic address information.

My REST controller is as follows:

```
package addressservice.controller;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.goodyear.menuadmin.plantservice.model.PlantInfo;
import com.goodyear.menuadmin.plantservice.service.PlantInfoService;

@Path("/")
public class AddressController {
    private AddressService service = new AddressService ();
    private Address address;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAddress(@Context ServletContext ctx) throws Exception {
        this.address= plantService.getInfo("Name");

        return Response.ok(this.plant, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_WILDCARD)
    private Response saveAddress(Address data) {
        boolean isOk = addressService.updateInfo(data);

        if(!isOk) {
            Response.serverError().build();
        }

        return Response.ok(data, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

However, when I execute this, I am receiving a 405 Method Not Allowed error. The post is initiated from a button click on a form.

The GET portion works just fine.

The response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: HEAD,GET,OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 10 Sep 2018 17:58:08 GMT
```

I've tried several different attempts to correct this ranging from adding this init parameter to my tomcat web.xml

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>readonly</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I've tried changing from `$.post` to the following:

```
return $.ajax({
   url: ctx + "/addressinfo/",
   type: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

> EDIT
>   I neglected to add the servlet definition for the application's web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Address Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>addressservice.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Plant Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addressinfo/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Nothing seems to be allowing me to post to my REST service.

Is there something I need to change in my Tomcat config? Or Am I doing something else wrong? I suppose I could change from a REST service to a servlet, But I would prefer to not have to do that.

Comment: You are POSTing to /plantinfo, but that does not match the @Path of your resource.

Comment: Thank you @luk2302. Please see my edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Java method for @POST is `private`, it should be `public`. Jersey ignores private methods in Controllers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my incompetence. I can't believe I missed that

Comment: no problem, it's just a small oversight, it happens..)